# declare var as a group in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization, declaration, var

I want to declare a group of the same objects like this.

```
var dave, paul, sam = UILabel()
```

I have tried various things. But I have not been able to do anything different to declare vars except the standard.

```
var dave = UILabel()
var paul = UILabel()
var sam = UILabel()
```

I would think there has to be someway to put this in a array to speed up the process.

Comment: Why have separate variables with people's names? Perhaps an array of labels would be better.

Comment: @rmaddy how do I do that?

Comment: @Rob how do i call the labels. Example do I do labels.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using named variables, you can just create an array of labels:

```
let labels = (0..<3).map { _ in UILabel() }
```

Or you might as well configure them as you create them:

```
let labels = (0..<3).map { _ -> UILabel in 
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}
```

You can do whatever other configuration of them you want in that closure.

Now you can use them. For example, you might add them to your view which already has a vertical stack view (which gets you out of the business of manually adding constraints for each label), like so:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for label in labels {
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
    }
}
```

And if you wanted to set the text for these labels:

```
labels[0].text = "Dave"
labels[1].text = "Paul"
labels[2].text = "Sam"
```

---

Here is a playground that illustrates the above:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        return stackView
    }()

    let labels = (0..<3).map { _ -> UILabel in 
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addStackView()
        addLabels()
        updateLabels()
    }
}

private extension ViewController {
    func addStackView() {
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func addLabels() {
        for label in labels {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }
    }

    func updateLabels() {
        labels[0].text = "Dave"
        labels[1].text = "Paul"
        labels[2].text = "Sam"
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Now, if this was a proper app rather than a playground, I’d probably just add the stack view in IB, with an `@IBOutlet`, rather than doing it programmatically, but I just wanted to illustrate the idea.